# View moving up in xamarin forms android when keyboard appears

Tags: android, xamarin, keyboard, xamarin.forms, window-soft-input-mode

The status bar and the screen moves up completely when the keyboard popsUp in xamarin forms android and the EditText field is in the bottom of the screen. I tried using

```
WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan
```

and

```
WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize
```

But unfortunately both are not working,i also clubbed both 
From a blog post i [read](https://xamarinhelp.com/accommodate-on-screen-keyboard-xamarin-forms/) putting

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

and

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{
    Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = 0;
    var statusBarHeightInfo = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("_statusBarHeight", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    statusBarHeightInfo.SetValue(this, 0);
    Window.SetStatusBarColor(new Android.Graphics.Color(0,0,0, 255)); // Change color as required.
 }
```

after launch application is an alternative, but unfortunately this also failed. Any other option available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bug in Xamarin. I used following code in mainActivity

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
    {
                    Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = 0;
                    var statusBarHeightInfo = typeof(FormsAppCompatActivity).GetField("_statusBarHeight", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    statusBarHeightInfo.SetValue(this, 50);
    }
```

And used

```
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

The problem was it wont work if you forcefully hide the title bar

```
Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never);
```

I commented out this code and the issue was solved. 
But due to resize property i faced lot of issue since i have designed screens with Grid and star value which caused many unwanted issues.
So i am not going to use this method sadly. :(